# Display negative numbers on a chloropleth map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, colorbar, colormap

How can I display negative numbers on a chloropleth map?

I have a GeoDataFrame with some negative and some positive values. However, the colormap/colorbar does not automatically adjust for the negative numbers. How can I make the colormap/colorbar adjust for negative numbers and put 0 in the middle of the colorbar?

```py
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# Create some negative values
for index, row in world.iterrows():
    if world.loc[index,'pop_est'] % 2 == 0:
        world.loc[index,'pop_est'] = world.loc[index,'pop_est'] * (-1)

# Plot
world.plot(column='pop_est', cmap='RdYlBu', legend=True)
```

[image]

Comment: That is certainly a bug. I have opened an issue for that https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1341.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and also for opening the bug. In the meantime, is there a workaround? Does not seem like an unusual task to plot negative values. :)

Comment: Correction. It is not a bug, it actually works. Just your example above is massively skewed by China. Just try `world = world[~world.name.isin(['India', 'China'])]` and then plot.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried with `world.loc[139,'pop_est'] = world.loc[139,'pop_est']*(-1)`. Then I guess I have to somewhow apply a log scale in both directions.